# UFW blocks traffic despite there is an allow rule

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, ufw, traffic

I have Ubuntu server with OpenVPN server running there.

IP addresses as follows:

- enp1s0: 192.168.3.67/24
- tun0: 172.18.37.1/24

OpenVPN is configured so that devices behind the VPN client are communicating through the VPN client and sending traffic to 172.18.37.1.

I need to allow inbound traffic to port 9001, but despite having a rule in place, UFW still blocks the traffic.

The log is here:

```
Feb 23 07:42:59 hidden kernel: [6300398.767241] [UFW BLOCK] IN=tun0 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.1.66.250 DST=172.18.37.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=37406 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40864 DPT=9001 WINDOW=251 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

UFW is here:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                   #
```

The 10.1.66.250 device is a device behind an OpenVPN client's LAN. Do you think UFW might find it confusing? Not sure.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I can also provide additional logs if required.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check all iptables rules, not only UFW. The order matters.